# Declare INDEX cluase in MIB without using the variable in table

Tags: snmp, mib

I'm finding the solution to declare INDEX clause without using/bind with any variable in MIB table.

Generally when declare INDEX clause I use 1 variable as index
e.g.

```
dataEntry OBJECT-TYPE
SYNTAX  dataEntry
ACCESS  not-accessible
STATUS  mandatory
DESCRIPTION
"The entry of data Table"
INDEX  { dataIndex }
   ::=  {  dataTable 1 }
dataEntry ::= SEQUENCE {
   dataIndex
      INTEGER,
   dataValue
      INTEGER
}
dataIndex OBJECT-TYPE
SYNTAX  INTEGER
ACCESS  read-only
STATUS  mandatory
DESCRIPTION
"The index of data table"
   ::=  {  dataEntry 1   }

dataValue OBJECT-TYPE
.
.
```

but what I want is use dataIndex in INDEX clause but will not declare it in SEQUENCE and variable. something right this

```
dataEntry OBJECT-TYPE
SYNTAX  dataEntry
ACCESS  not-accessible
STATUS  mandatory
DESCRIPTION
"The entry of data Table"
INDEX  { dataIndex }
   ::=  {  dataTable 1 }
dataEntry ::= SEQUENCE {
   dataValue
      INTEGER
}
dataValue OBJECT-TYPE
.
.
```

What I wrote is compiled error for sure, but is it have possible solution for what I want?

Comment: If your intention is to invent your own standard, make sure you don't call it MIB to avoid confusing others.

Comment: Hi @LexLi , I'm not try to invent my own standard. I just not sure is it possible in MIB standard. thank you for replying.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of reinventing the wheel please consider learning the following parts of SMI standards:

**Augmented Table:** Augmented Table comes in to picture when there is one-to-one dependency between rows of one table and rows in another table. Wherein one table is the base and the other augmenting table. This might arise when a particular MIB imports another MIB and shares the same table (A classic example is If-MIB imports the group interfaces defined in RFC1213-MIB, where IF-MIB augments the ifTable defined in RFC1213-MIB)

**Tables with External index:**
These tables are similar to the augmented tables which shares the index values with other tables except that these are SMIv1 tables and the augmented tables are SMIv2 tables.

Comment: Thank you for advice, I will take a look on it

Comment: You copy/pasted this from https://www.webnms.com/snmp/help/snmpapi/snmpv3/table_handling/snmptables_basics.html without giving any attribution.